$L^1$ norm of Fourier transform of $C_c^\infty$ bounded by $L^\infty$ norm of some derivatives
I encountered the question: for $B$ the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $N>n/2$, $$D_N:=\{\phi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n): \text{supp}\ \phi\subseteq B, \|D^\alpha\phi\|_\infty\leq 1, 0\leq |\alpha|\leq N\}.$$ $S(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is schwartz space and $S'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is its dual space. Suppose $K\in S'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and is locally integrable except $x=0$. Prove that if the Fourier transform $\hat{K}\in L^\infty$, then $\sup_{\phi\in D_N,R>0} |K(\phi^R)|\leq A$ a constant, where $\phi^R(x):=\phi(x/R)$.
My attempt: It's easy to use properties of Fourier transform to get
$$|K(\phi^R)| = |\langle\hat{K},\hat{\phi^R}\rangle|\leq \|\hat{K}\|_\infty \|\hat{\phi^R}\|_1 = \|\hat{K}\|_\infty \|\hat{\phi}\|_1, $$
so we only need to bound $\|\hat{\phi}\|_1$. I hope that I can use $|x|^{n+1}|\hat{\phi}| \leq C |\widehat{D^{n+1} \phi}|$ so that I can get a uniform $|x|^{-(n+1)}$ decay of $\hat {\phi}$. However I can only get derivative bound up to order $n/2$.
I wonder if there's any better way to bound the $L^1$ norm of Fourier transform of a compactly support function, only using norms of some low order derivatives. Does the $n/2$ derivative hint me to use something like Sobolev Embedding? I really have no idea. Anyone has some idea to help me with it? Thanks!

By the way, it's a part of a complete problem. The complete problem has another requirement that $|K(x)| + |x||\nabla K(x)|\leq A_1 |x|^{-n}$ which is the standard kernel condition in singular integral. The complete problem is to prove that $\hat{K}\in L^\infty$ is equivalent to the sup (in my post) bounded.

I think I figured out one solution. Separate $L^1$ norm into $\int_B |\hat{\phi}| + \int_{\mathbb{R}^n-B} |\hat{\phi}| = I + II$.
For I, $$I = \int_B |\hat{\phi}| \leq |B| |\hat{\phi}|_\infty \leq |B| |\phi|_1 \leq |B|^2 |\phi|_\infty \leq |B|^2.$$
For II, $$II = \sum_{l=0}^\infty \int_{2^l\leq |\xi|\le 2^{l+1}} |\hat{\phi}| \leq C\sum_{l=0}^\infty 2^{ln/2} (\int_{2^l\leq |\xi|\le 2^{l+1}} |\hat{\phi}|^2)^{1/2} =: C\sum_{l=0}^\infty 2^{ln/2} S_l^{1/2}, $$
$$S_l = \int_{2^l\leq |\xi|\le 2^{l+1}} |\hat{\phi}|^2 \leq_{(*)} C \int_{2^l\leq |\xi|\le 2^{l+1}} |\xi|^{-2N}|\widehat{D^N\phi}|^2\leq C 2^{-2lN} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |D^N \phi|^2.$$
Since supp $\phi \subseteq B$, we have
$$S_l \leq C 2^{-2lN} |B|\|D^N \phi\|_\infty^2 \leq C|B| 2^{-2lN},$$
therefore by $2N>n$, we have $$II\leq C\sum_{l=0}^\infty 2^{l(n-2N)/2} \leq A.$$

(*) might need more explanation, you can decomposite the domain into pieces where you can determine $\xi = (\xi_1,...,\xi_n)$ which coordinate is the largest.
